# How to return Http response and render with context at the same time?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, web-deployment

In my web application made with django, I am trying to upload a excel file and it will do a certain calculation from the data of the file and will auto export the updated file. But at the same time I want to show specific information into a template.

Here is the code from my views.py that I tried

```
context = {'mttr_count': mttr_count, 'mttr_avg': mttr_avg, 'data':sheet}
        
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mttr.xls"'
rendered = render_to_string('mttr/mttr-output.html', context)
response = HttpResponse(rendered)
wb.save(response)
return response
```

But it does not give the desired result. How do I make it so that upon file upload and pressing the submit button, it will render the 'mttr.html' template with data in 'context' and will also download the modified file?

Comment: isn't it possible to load the file in the view, then create a context and pass it to the template?